# Fedora 23 server can't boot after renaming volume group in cockpit

Tags: fedora

I've installed Fedora 23 as web server and it was working so well for some reason i can't remember i decided to rename the volume group in storage section in cockpit the name was generated automatically during  installation and it was something like

```
Fedora_dhcp-192-168-00-00
```

after rebooting it can't boot and can't find `/root`, `/swap` volumes because it's still looking for them in the old directory

```
/dev/Fedora_dhcp-192-168-00-00
```

now I need to restore my system. The error message is

```
dracut-initqueue[303]: warning
```

Comment: You should be able to repair it from the dracut emergency shell.

Comment: yes i need to know how can i repair it

Comment: Then change the volume group name back to what it was before.

Comment: i changed it in the first time from a GUI (cockpit) , I need to know how can i change it back from the emergency shell

Answer (score 1):

In a normal shell, you can rename a volume group with `vgrename`.

```
vgrename oldname newname
```

Embedded environments like the emergency shell may require you to call `lvm` explicitly:

```
lvm vgrename oldname newname
```

Comment: when trying to rename the volume group the result is
lvm vgrename test.anhri.lan fedora_dhcp-192-168-10-190
Read-only locking type set. Write locks are prohibited.
can't get lock for fedora_dhcp-192-168-10-190

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out 
it was about editing

> /etc/lvm/lvm.conf.

then renaming the lvgroup back to the old name 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If one wishes to keep the volume group name, then the name in the boot entry should to modified.
For `systemd-boot`, the entry is in `EFI System Partition/loader/entries/`. There is an option with the group name, e.g. `rd.lvm.lv=Fedora_dhcp-192-168-00-00/root`.
For `GRUB2`, the entry seems to be in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, though I'm not familiar with it...

Also edit the name in `/etc/kernel/cmdline`, the boot entry gets its options from here.

p.s. I just had the same problem on Fedora Server 39.